# /var/log consistently cleared on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog

On Ubuntu 22.04, /var/log is consistently cleared when log files should be present. rsyslog is installed and running. Restarting rsyslog shows files being created again in /var/log (such as auth.log, kern.log, other non-default logging, etc), but mere seconds later everything disappears. There are no cronjobs that could be causing this.

The server in question is used as a SIEM server, which we have for many other clients with the same configurations, including rsyslog.conf, where this appears to be an isolated issue. Looking around online, I can't seem to find mention of this exact issue, and as far as I'm aware we don't have other software on the server that would be causing this.

I've so far tried the below:

- systemctl restart rsyslog
- systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket
- systemctl restart systemd-journald
- reboot server
- ps aux | grep rsyslog (to check if running)
- rsyslogd -N1 (to check for errors, none)

Attempting a test log:

```
user@hostname:/home/user# logger -p mail.info "TEST"
user@hostname:/home/user# cat /var/log/mail.log
Nov  1 14:22:43 hostname user: TEST
```

Checking the service is up:

```
syslog      6483  0.0  0.0 222300  3412 ?        Ssl  11:55   0:00 rsyslogd
syslog     56507  0.0  0.0 222300  4608 ?        Ssl  12:52   0:01 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
```

Checking the service and version:

```
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-11-01 12:52:54 UTC; 1h 20min ago
TriggeredBy: ● syslog.socket
       Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
             man:rsyslog.conf(5)
             https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
    Process: 56503 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/rsyslog/reload-apparmor-profile (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 56507 (rsyslogd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 19031)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 1.328s
     CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
             └─56507 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE

Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname systemd[1]: Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname rsyslogd[56507]: imuxsock: Acquired UNIX socket '/run/systemd/journal/syslog' (fd 3) from systemd.  [v8.23>
Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname rsyslogd[56507]: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 109
Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname systemd[1]: Started rsyslog.service - System Logging Service.
Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname rsyslogd[56507]: rsyslogd's userid changed to 103
Nov 01 12:52:54 hostname rsyslogd[56507]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2302.0" x-pid="56507" x-info="https://www.rsyslo>
lines 1-21/21 (END)

rsyslogd  8.2302.0 (aka 2023.02) compiled with:
        PLATFORM:                               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
        PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        memory allocator:                       system default
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes
        systemd support:                        Yes
        Config file:                            /etc/rsyslog.conf
        PID file:                               /run/rsyslogd.pid
        Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.